# Change the background color of Fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

I want to make the background color of Fancybox transparent.

The obvious way is to use ".fancybox-skin" in your CSS, but this will affect all fancyboxes, and I need it to vary. Thus the setting needs to be sent with wrapCSS.

Fancybox has a parameter "wrapCSS" that can be passed in with the original js call, but I'm not sure how to use it. It just says "string": http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful

I've been trying to pass in the CSS like `{wrapCSS: "background: red"}`, but it's not working.

Comment: Check this :
http://jsfiddle.net/jRsjK/

Comment: That's for changing the overlay, not the background color of the content box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use wrapCSS to add a class, then in your CSS:

```
.whateverYouChooseforWrapCSS .fancybox-skin {
  background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use css for bg:

```
#fancy_bg
{
    background-color:000000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Before anyone chooses to [recommend deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11118372) of this post, this is a valid attempted answer. This post should not have been flagged and should not be recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ. See: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)